# SOQL Code error

Tags: soql

Could someone, please, help with this. Below is my field label, name and data type:

Field Label     Field name          Data Type
Owner           Owner               Lookup(User,Queue)

I wrote this SOQL

SELECT Owner__r.Queue
FROM BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c

The fields as decribed in my wsdl is below:

SOQL is saying that it does not understand the relationship. How can I get this working?

Many thanks.

Regards,
Holla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OwnerId` is a standard field and therefore does not require the `__r` suffix. When using a standard lookup field as a relationship just drop the `Id` from the API name.

```
SELECT OwnerId, Owner.Name FROM BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c
```

In this case `OwnerId` will be the record Id of the User or Queue, while `Owner.Name` will the the record's Name.

Comment: Hi ScottW, Are you able to help me with this - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67823/pushing-attachment-through-apex-web-services?noredirect=1#comment88742_67823